akka.net cluster forming with ssl support - Received InitJoin message from ... but this node is not initialized yet
i'm trying to form a cluster of 2 nodes using akka.net (seed + work) hosted in .net web api on local windows machine.
Problem is that exact code runs fine for no-ssl but for case with ssl support i get this error message on seed side "Received InitJoin message from ... but this node is not initialized yet".
I'm not sure what is the problem.
Here is a config for seed node:
"Akka": {
    "enabled": true,
    "loglevel": "INFO",
    "actor": {
      "provider": "cluster" // enable clustering
    },
    "extensions": [
      "Akka.Cluster.Tools.PublishSubscribe.DistributedPubSubExtensionProvider,Akka.Cluster.Tools"
    ],
    "remote": {
      "log-remote-lifecycle-events": "DEBUG",
      "dot-netty": {
        "tcp": {
          "port": 55555,
          "hostname": "localhost",
          "log-transport": true,
          "enable-ssl": true,
          "ssl": {
            "suppress-validation": true,
            "certificate": {
              "path": "localhost.pfx",
              "password": "P@55w0rd"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "cluster": {
        "log-info": "off",
        "log-info-verbose": "on",
        "seed-nodes": [
          "akka.ssl.tcp://devonbike-cluster@localhost:55555" // main seed node's address
        ],
        "roles": [
          "seed"
        ]
      }
    }
  }

for a worker node configuration is like this:
"Akka": {
    "enabled": true,
    "loglevel": "INFO",
    "actor": {
      "provider": "cluster"
    },
    "extensions": [
      "Akka.Cluster.Tools.PublishSubscribe.DistributedPubSubExtensionProvider,Akka.Cluster.Tools"
    ],
    "remote": {
      "log-remote-lifecycle-events": "DEBUG",
      "dot-netty": {
        "tcp": {
          "port": 0,
          "hostname": "localhost",
          "log-transport": true,
          "enable-ssl": true,
          "ssl": {
            "suppress-validation": true,
            "certificate": {
              "path": "localhost.pfx",
              "password": "P@55w0rd"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "cluster": {
      "seed-nodes": [
        "akka.ssl.tcp://devonbike-cluster@localhost:55555" // main seed node's address
      ],
      "roles": [
        "worker"
      ]
    }
  }

Full source code is available: https://github.com/DevOnBike/webapi-playground
